# Explorer in Treeview

Tags: c#, treeview, explorer

[image]

how to do this in Treeview control? I'm using C#, I do some research but it is so very difficult to get only the desktop... I can get the logical drivers, but I need to get "DESKTOP" only and it will expand to show "My Documents", "My Computer" and other items that can see in my desktop.

Comment: I tried to put my logical driver in the treeview.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, are you trying to figure out how to place something a the top of a treeview or do you need to know how to get the "Desktop" special folder?

Comment: I need to put the desktop in the treeview, just like in the image above.

Comment: Now i got it. I think you want to have Collapse/all [+] icon in front of "Desktop" so you can open and close it when you want. isn't it?

Comment: yes, and also the other icon, I can see there files and folders.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace DesktopTreeView
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadFoldersInTreeView(treeView1);
    }

    void LoadFoldersInTreeView(TreeView treeName)
    {
        treeName.BeginUpdate();
        treeName.Nodes.Add("Desktop");
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
        node.Text = "My Computer";
        treeName.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(node);
    }
 }
}
```

And results are  shows as below:

[image]